# Django Rest framework | TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict()

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

### I am trying to upload a product with multiple images and have a category or a author of a product. but getting a error TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict().

### Models.py##

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
price = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
discount = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
length = models.CharField(max_length=100)
width = models.CharField(max_length=100)
depth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User, editable=False, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=statuses, default='1')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    db_table = 'products'
    verbose_name = 'Product'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
```

### Serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
author = AuthorSerializer(many=False,)
category = ProductCategorySerializer(many=False,)
images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'discount',
              'length', 'width', 'depth', 'status', 'images', 'category', 'author', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

def create(self, validated_data):
    name = validated_data.get("name")
    description = validated_data.get("description")
    price = validated_data.get("price")
    discount = validated_data.get("discount")
    length = validated_data.get("length")
    width = validated_data.get("width")
    depth = validated_data.get("depth")
    status = validated_data.get("status")
    category = validated_data.get('category')
    # category = validated_data.pop('category')
    author = validated_data.get("author")
    # author = validated_data.pop('author')


    imgs = self.context.get('view').request.FILES
    product = Product.objects.create(
        name=name,
        description=description,
        price=price,
        discount=discount,
        length=length,
        width=width,
        depth=depth,
        status=status,
        category_id=category,
        author_id=author
    )
    for image in imgs.values():
        ProductImage.objects.create(image=image, product=product)
    return product
```

### Views.py

```
class ProductApi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('id')
serializer_class = ProductSerializer
parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
filterset_fields = ["id", "name", "description",
                    "length", "width", "depth", "status"]
pagination_class = pagination
authentication_classes = authclass
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated]
```

### Urls.py

```
router.register("category", CategoryApi, basename="AdminCategoryApi")
router.register("product", ProductApi, basename="AdminProductApi")
```

### Index.js

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#create', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formdata = new FormData(this);
    const name = $("#name").val();
    const description = $("#description").val();
    const price = $("#price").val();
    const discount = $("#discount").val();
    const length = $("#length").val();
    const width = $("#width").val();
    const depth = $("#depth").val();
    const category = $("#category").val();
    const status = $("#sstatus").val();
    const images = $('#image')[0].files

    if (name == "") {
        msgError("Name is required", "#response");
    } else if (description == "") {
        msgError("Description is required", "#response");
    } else if (price == "") {
        msgError("Price is required", "#response");
    } else if (length == "") {
        msgError("Length is required", "#response");
    } else if (width == "") {
        msgError("Width is required", "#response");
    } else if (depth == "") {
        msgError("Depth is required", "#response");
    } else if (category == "") {
        msgError("Category is required", "#response");
    } else if (status == "") {
        msgError("Status is required", "#response");
    } else {
        formdata.append('name', name);
        formdata.append('description', description);
        formdata.append('price', price);
        formdata.append('discount', discount);
        formdata.append('length', length);
        formdata.append('width', width);
        formdata.append('depth', depth);
        formdata.append('status', status);
        formdata.append('category.id', category);
        formdata.append('author.id', user_id);


        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            formdata.append("images.image", images[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: BASEURL("api/admin/product/"),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': token,
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#btnsubmit").html(`<div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light"></div>`);
                $("#btnsubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                if (response) {
                    msgSuccess("I record created successfully", "#response");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#btnsubmit").html(`Submit`);
                $("#btnsubmit").attr("disabled", false);
            },
            error: function (response, exception) {
                console.log(response)

                var msg = '';
                const data = response.responseJSON
                if (response.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (response.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (response.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (response.status == 401) {
                    msgSuccess("Your session timesout", "#response");
                    setTimeout(function () { window.open("/", '_self') }, 1000);
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else if (data["name"]) {
                    msg = data["name"][0];
                } else if (data["description"]) {
                    msg = data["description"][0];
                } else if (data["price"]) {
                    msg = data["price"][0];
                } else if (data["discount"]) {
                    msg = data["discount"][0];
                } else if (data["length"]) {
                    msg = data["length"][0];
                } else if (data["width"]) {
                    msg = data["width"][0];
                } else if (data["depth"]) {
                    msg = data["depth"][0];
                } else if (data["category"]) {
                    msg = data["category"][0];
                } else if (data["status"]) {
                    msg = data["status"][0];
                } else if (data["image"]) {
                    msg = data["image"][0];
                }
                msgError(msg, '#response');
            },
        });
    }

});
```

So this is the actual code. Not getting the required output. Help me to find out the actual issue.

Comment: Do you know what line the error is on?

Comment: category = validated_data.get('category')
        author = validated_data.get("author")

Comment: Category is a different model or author is a User_auth_model so i have to insert the user_id and category_id in product table like this.
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, editable=False, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)